# How can I set the height of a div in a content page using percentage?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am trying to give height to the outermost div in % but it is not increasing whereas when I give in em its working fine. Please help.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="background-color:Blue; height:50%">
  <div style="width:50%;
    height:50%;
    margin:0 auto">`enter code here`
<div style="width:34%;float:left;display:inline; height:100%">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"  style="width:100%;  height:100%"       ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div style="width:33%; float:left;display:inline; height: 100%;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%">  </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div style=" width:33%; float:left;display:inline; height: 100%;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="95%" Height="100%">  </asp:TextBox> 
    </div>
   </div> 
   </div></form>
```

Comment: give the parent i.e. the form a fixed height, otherwise the browser has no reference height to base the 50% on ...

Answer (score 7):

A percentage height is relative to the height of the parent element.  In this case, the form element.  If your intent is to have the div be 50% of the page height, you will need to make the form `height: 50%`, the `div` `height: 100%` and assuming the form has no parent, give the `html` and `body` a height:

```
html,body{
     height: 100%;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2gY7/

Comment: In his specific situation: http://jsfiddle.net/CyAQ9/ with added CSS: html, body, #form1 { height:100%; }

Comment: @nathan Didn't want to make any assumptions about the remainder of his page.  If he has other stuff after the form this could cause issues having the form with 100% height.

Comment: Point well taken. =) I actually hadn't noticed that you had advised changing the height of the form to 50%. Without changing the height of the form to _something_, the solution does indeed not work.

Answer (score 0):

**simple**

your body & html sizes should have height of 100% first.

this is called "resetting css"